# How to get folder ID for uploading documents in Lightning?

Tags: rest-api, rest, files

I'm trying to use the REST API to upload a File. Eventually I want to associate this File with a specific account.

I'm following [these instructions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) to upload a binary file, where part of the body looks like:

```
{  
    "Description" : "Marketing brochure for Q1 2011",
    "Keywords" : "marketing,sales,update",
    "FolderId" : "0017A00000VAQcxQAH",
    "Name" : "Marketing Brochure Q1",
    "Type" : "png"
}
```

I'm having trouble finding and using a FolderId. In my sandbox (service cloud), I go to App Launcher > Files > Libraries > New Library, and inside of that I create a new folder. I can see the folder here. However, there's no ID for the folder listed, and it's not in the URL.

If I run this SOQL query in a developer console:

```
SELECT Id, CreatedDate, Name FROM Folder ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

I can see lots of folders created by other users in my instance, however I don't see my newly created folder, including if I search `WHERE Name = 'My New Folder'`.

1. How do I find the Folder ID to associate document uploads with?
2. Is it possible to upload a document and associate it directly with an Account so it appears in that Account's files tab? I tried passing in `"ParentId": "RECORD_ID"` but it errors with `"No such column 'ParentId' on sobject of type Document"`.

Comment: Am I missing any permissions on my user?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions you are following is for document object  which is classic specific.

in app launcher -. files -> libraries ,   the available library and folder is for content, not for document.

You should create a content and not a document.
please review the same instructions  to upload content version  and not document.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm#inserting_a_contentversion

to link account to that content ,  3 objects will be involved.please read about them and implement your logic.
objects will be
Contentdocument  -  will represent document
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm

contentversion   -  different versions of document.  one version will be latest   with islatest = true.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm

contentdocumentlink   will store relation between document  and record(Account in your case)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm